# When TTL expires in non primary key columns the row does not get deleted after update

Tags: java, cassandra

According to the Cassandra documentation both insert and update behave the same. But if I try the following commands:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_keyspace.users (
   userId UUID,
   name TEXT,
   surname TEXT,
   phone TEXT
   PRIMARY KEY (userId, name, surname)
);

INSERT INTO my_keyspace.users (userId, name, surname, phone) 
VALUES (6f4c9ece-d47e-4582-a9e3-6c6f740f47d6, 'John', 'Doe', '555 5555 555') USING TTL 20;

UPDATE my_keyspace.users  USING TTL 10 SET phone = '777 777 777'
WHERE userId = 6f4c9ece-d47e-4582-a9e3-6c6f740f47d6 AND name = 'John' AND surname = 'Doe'
IF phone = '555 5555 555';
```

The column value is set to NULL in 10s and in 20s the entire row is deleted

But if I try this:

```
UPDATE my_keyspace.users  USING TTL 20 SET phone = '777 777 777' WHERE userId = 6f4c9ece-d47e-4582-a9e3-6c6f740f47d6 AND name = 'John' AND surname = 'Doe';

UPDATE my_keyspace.users  USING TTL 10 SET phone = '777 777 777' WHERE userId = 6f4c9ece-d47e-4582-a9e3-6c6f740f47d6 AND name = 'John' AND surname = 'Doe' IF phone = '555 5555 555';
```

The entire row is deleted in 10s.

Can anyone explain why the behavior is different in this scenario and how the primary key column actually decide when to delete themselves?

Answer (score 0):

The row will be removed when the TTL of the primary key has expired AND all of its columns TTLs have expired.

You cannot change the TTL of a primary key column in an update statement, you can upsert it with a new TTL value (as of Cassandra 2.2.1 this works for TTL's less than the original).

It's likely that the time taken for you to do the second set of update statements is long enough for the entire row to expire. I can't replicate it as you say myself. Try setting the INSERT's TTL to a much higher value, then trying to observe it as you say again.